# How to get the URLs of sign document link of Docusign in our app?

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any way to display all the documents/envelopes which are needed to be signed by the user in our app? or list all the links of these envelopes in our app so that when the user clicks it will take to Docusign UI same as how it works with email
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDqq9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but there are some things to consider.
First, you will need to make API calls to find all the envelopes that needed to be signed by the user.

From the [Java SDK](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.docusign/docusign-esign-java/latest/com/docusign/esign/api/EnvelopesApi.html) use the `ListStatusChanges` method to do that.

Then, for each envelope you found in the right status, you will want to generate a URL using the [embedded signing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded/) feature.

However, don't do that when the page loads! These URLs expire after 2 min and so what you want is to generate them when the user clicks and redirect to the generated URL dynamically, or you'll have issues with the app.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  
To use the embedded signing feature do we need to send envelopes using our app? Or do we get all envelopes that are sent using the Docusign app?
Do we have any endpoint to get all the envelopes based on recipient details like email id or name?  
If possible can you please provide any example endpoints?

Comment: You can generate an embedded signing URL to envelopes that were not sent from your app.

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/
If your app is using Auth Code Grant with the logged in credentials, then you can use "awaiting_my_signature" as the folder name and you'll get the list.

Comment: {{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/views/recipient
With is endpoint I am able to get the URL. But when I open the URL is displays a document without giving the signature option this envelope sends to other users. If I send to my account then I can see the signature option as I was logged in to Docusign.

Comment: Endpoint: {{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/views/recipient
I am passing input JSON as
{
  "userName": "Joao",
  "email": "",
  "returnUrl": "https://www.sample.com",
  "authenticationMethod": "email",
  "recipientId": "2",
  "userId": "",
  "recipientIdGuid": ""
}

Comment: You need to pass correct information in the body of the JSON to the endpoint. You are missing clientUserId for one.

Comment: clientUserId must match what was passed to the recipient

Comment: If you didn't create the recipient from your code, you will need to update it to have the clientUserId

Comment: when I create recipients and create envelopes using DocuSign app and by using endpoints I am trying to generate an URL in my app then how I can set clientUserId to recipients?

Comment: do I get clientUserId in the recipient array when I try to get all recipients along with envelopes if I set clientUserId?

Comment: No, you will have to make an update to the recipients of the envelope first

Comment: so, first step - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/update/

Comment: Then you can make the PUT call to generate the URL by using the same clientUserId

Comment: It's working!! Thank you @Inbar Gazit.  The last question I want to ask you is right now I running all the direct APIsin postman. Can I access Direct APIs in my app instead of using SDK? As my app is designed using flutter and all my app endpoints are created using Springboot. So can call direct APIs using Feignclient in Springboot to create my own endpoint to list all the envelopes for one recipient?

Comment: Do we have any endpoint to get all the envelopes by using the recipient name or email id? for example XYZ user needs to sign in 2 envelopes then using XYZ can we be able to fetch those 2 envelopes?

Comment: Can you please answer to this .https://stackoverflow.com/q/70267367/2369052

Comment: done :) sorry for the delay