# Can I access Direct APIs in my app instead of using Docusign SDK and is there any endpoint to get envelopes based on recipient email id or name?

Tags: spring-boot, docusignapi, spring-cloud-feign

As my app is designed using flutter and all my app endpoints are created using Springboot. So can call direct APIs using Feignclient in Springboot to create my own endpoint to list all the envelopes for one recipient?

Do we have any endpoint to get all the envelopes by using the recipient name or email id? for example XYZ user needs to sign in 2 envelopes then using XYZ can we be able to fetch those 2 envelopes?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check/accept the best answer for your question. ***Thank you!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are very welcome to call the eSignature REST API directly and not use an SDK. Use API version 2.1. About half of the developers who use the API do so directly.

### Updated: authentication

To call the eSign REST API, each of your API calls must include authentication via an access token. You can obtain an access token via an OAuth flow.

If your users have DocuSign user accounts, then they should login/authenticate via Implicit grant assuming that you're using Flutter for a mobile app.

If your users don't have DocuSign accounts (they are signers, not senders), then you need to have a backend server that can securely use the JWT grant flow to obtain an access token on behalf of a "system" account such as "finance@example.com"

If you have questions about authentication, please open a new question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for responding. This answer boosts me a lot.  I am more confused with an authentication process. I tried with the code example provided in github.com/docusign. Every time it is taking me to the Docusign login screen whenever I try to call any endpoint. Can you please provide me some example tutorials or video calling eSignature REST API directly using FeignClient. It will help me to the core

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Can you please comment on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70295330/is-there-any-example-source-code-in-spring-boot-and-feign-available-for-calling

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/
This endpoint has lots of filtering options including:

`email={email_address}` Limit results to envelopes sent by the account user with this email address.

user_name must be given as well, and both email and user_name must refer to an existing account user.

`user_name={user_name}` Limit results to envelopes sent by the account user with this user name.

email must be given as well, and both email and user_name must refer to an existing account user.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  Does account user mean a recipient should have a DocuSign account?
{
    "errorCode": "USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST_IN_SYSTEM",
    "message": "The UserID did not identify a User in the system."
}
When I tried with one recipient who does not have an account in Docusign.

Comment: And How about the first question. Calling endpoints using feign, is it possible?

Comment: I have no experience with feign, so I don't know, I'm sorry, I was only answering part of your question

Comment: as for the users, since your other question indicated you are building some website where users will be able to sign envelopes they need to sign - I assume that means they have a userId in the account, otherwise how do they log in?

Comment: No problem I understood thank you. These users' authorization will be done in my app. All I need to do is to list all the envelopes which are needed to sign by that particular user and when the user clicks on the single envelope then I am going to generate a URL using the "%/views/recipient%" endpoint. In simple phrases along with sending email, we want to give an option to users to sign the envelope in our app instead of opening an email inbox.