# Is there any example source code in spring boot and feign available for calling docusign eSignature REST API directly and not use an SDK?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docusignapi, spring-resttemplate

I am trying to implement a spring boot application with DocuSign for getting all Envelopes and generating signing ceremony URL links for individual Envelopes which will be displayed in my app to the signer. I am not able to do it because I am not getting how to do authentication and which type of authentication I need to use. Should I use SDK or without SDK I should do? Any example source code for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it sounds like the people who will use your app are signers. Therefore they will typically not have a DocuSign account login.

So:

1. You should use DocuSign's JWT OAuth flow. Use it to obtain an access token for a "system user" in your DocuSign account such as hr_department@yourcompany.com
2. Use the user version of the JWT flow, not the application version. Here is the implementation of the [requestJWTUserToken](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/esign/client/ApiClient.java#L882) method.
3. Best would be to include the SDK in your project and call the `requestJWTUserToken` method. If you can't do that, then you can copy the source into your app.
4. The SDK works with Spring-Boot.
5. Use the resulting access token in your app to call the eSignature REST API

Comment: so, I already have Resteasy implementation in my Spring Boot project coming from another third party library. In this scenario, I was thinking about generate some client code using the OAI and integrate with DocuSign API via Feign Client. Any advice on that? Would it be a straight and forward implementation or are there some idiosyncrasies in the SDK that I should know about it?

Comment: Please ask as a new question. And please try it first in order to ask a good question

Comment: Ok. I will give it a try.